# Upgrading node.js on aws opsworks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

By default aws opsworks provides a node layer with node v0.10.33 . The latest stable version of node.js is 0.12.2. How can I upgrade the node version of my instances in the node layer of opsworks

Answer (score 1):

I have also been looking around for approaches to make this happen in a sustainable way, meaning that the configuration would apply to all instances of a stack. This implies some chef configuration.

Unfortunately, the node version is not configurable via the standard methods described in the [customization guide for Opsworks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/customizing.html).

So it seems like you would indeed have to write a wrapper cookbook to make this happen. I found this [cookbook-wrapper on github](https://github.com/zupper/nodejs-wrapper-opsworks) and you might want to use or fork it. I have not tested it though, but in general that's the way to go for the moment.

Another problem is that the main reason to use node 0.12+ is using generators and that requires the activation via a harmony flag. The cookbook has to support modifying the harmony-flags in its cookbook attributes to use this feature.

Answer (score -1):

ssh into your instance,and execute following

```
 sudo npm cache clean -f
 sudo npm install -g n
 sudo n stable
```

Comment: This change would only apply to this single instance and would be lost when renewing the instance.